# Как не закрывать popup, пока мышка на него наведена?

Tags: jquery, leafletjs, popup

Я использую `Leaflet js`. Каждый маркер имеет `popup` который всплывает при наведении курсора (`mouseover`):

```
myLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.layer.openPopup();
});
```

И пропадает при (`mouseout`)

```
myLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    e.layer.closePopup();
});
```

Все работает отлично.

Вопрос: Как Не закрывать `popup`, пока мышка на него наведена?

Answer (score 1):

Вместо того, чтобы закрывать `popup` сразу повесьте таймер на закрытие, например, с помощью `setTimeout()`.

Далее:

- добавьте слушатель события `mouseover` на содержимое `popup`
- добавьте слушатель события `mouseout` на содержимое `popup`
- при наведении на `popup` реализуйте сброс таймера на закрытие
- при покидании зоны `popup` реализуйте повторный запуск таймера или закрывайте `popup` сразу